# Two way ssl with Tomcat as client to weblogic

Tags: tomcat, ssl, weblogic, two-way

I have setup two-way SSL for Weblogic 9.2 for one of my project.  The setup was not difficult at all when a browser is a client.

I need to setup tomcat as a client now instead using a browser client.  In this scenario, Tomcat will host a JSP page or a servlet and call a web service hosted on Weblogic.  I have Googled but have not found much documentation for this setup.  Any idea - will setting the HTTPS connector work in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't adding the key and certificate to the tomcat keystore do the trick?

Comment: I generated a client certificate using weblogic CertGen utility and then imported it to a keystore using weblogic importPrivatekey.  The result is a keystore file, which I used in server.xml.  when I try to run my application, i get the following error  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to configure it the following way.

**SSL set up for Weblogic server**
Generate server private key and certificate

`java utils.CertGen -selfsigned -certfile SelfCA.cer -keyfile SelfKey.key -keyfilepass password -cn "localhost"`

Create identity key-store

`java utils.ImportPrivateKey -keystore IdentityStore.jks -storepass password -keypass password -alias trustself -certfile SelfCA.cer.pem -keyfile SelfKey.key.pem -keyfilepass password`

Import certificate into the new trust keystore

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias trustself -keystore truststore.jks -file SelfCA.cer.der -keyalg RSA`

When prompted for "Enter keystore password", enter "keypassword"

Log into WL administrative console (http://www.xyz.com:7001/console) (default username=weblogic and password=weblogic).  In my example I started “Weblogic Example Server”

Navigate to Server->Example Server->Keystore.

Click on “Lock and Edit”

Enter the following information

> Keystore dropdown menu: select “Custom Identity and Custom Trust”
>
> Custom Identity Keystore: [LOCATION]\IdentityStore.jks
>
> Custom Indentity Keystore Type: JKS
>
> Custom Identity Keystore Passphrase: password
>
> Custom Trust Keystore: [LOCATION]\truststore.jks
>
> Custom Trust Keystore Type: JKS
>
> Custom Trust Keystore Passphrase: keypassword`

Navigate to SSL tab.  Enter the following information

> Identity and Trust Location: Keystores
>
> Private Key Alias: trustself
>
> Private Key Passphrase: password

**Set up Tomcat Client**

Generate a certificate for Tomcat

`keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -validity 3650 -keystore client.jks -storepass abcd1234 -keypass abcd1234`

`keytool -export -alias client -keystore client.jks -storepass abcd1234 -file client.cer`

Import the certificate to truststore created above

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias trustclient -keystore truststore.jks -file client.cer -keyalg RSA`

Open [TOMCAT-INSTALL-LOCATION]\bin\catalina.bat in a text editor.
Add the following entries right after line 187

`set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/certs2/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=keypassword  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyAlias=trustcleint`

`set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/certs2/client.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=abcd1234`

Start tomcat.

**Testing**
Build an web application and deploy in Tomcat.  From the JSP page in web application invoke sayHello() method of web service `https://www.xyz.com:7002/jws_basic_simple/SimpleService` deployed in WebLogic.

Comment: Thanks to the following links http://www.jmezze.net/2011/04/two-way-mutual-ssl-authentication.html and http://www.wikiconsole.com/wiki/?p=312