# Establishing Trust between Servers

Tags: tomcat, ssl, weblogic, keystore, trust

I have 2 java webapp servers and I need to establish trust between them. One is weblogic, the other a tomcat. My wildcard cert is in use on the tc server in a keystore, the wls is just being configured....soon to have a keystore which I'll create. I think my issue would be the same even with 2 tc servers.

Which would be the proper way to establish trust:

- import the wildcard cert into the wls keystore as a trusted certificate? If so, does this mean the wls would trust all hosts presenting my wildcard cert? Are additional steps needed here, like importing the CA root cert?

or

- import a host specific (self-signed) certificate generated and exported from the the tc server? If so, does this mean the wls would trust only the tc host? Are there no chain of trust issues here?

I'm not sure if either of these are correct or work the way I think...I'm just reading the docs and having trouble finding this specific answer.

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Have you looked at other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290992/two-way-ssl-with-tomcat-as-client-to-weblogic